# What happens to index once the table got dropped?

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-drop

After dropping the table, found that the index created on the columns of the dropped table is gone. I just want to know what happens after that. Could someone please explain?

What all are the others getting dropped along with table drop?

Comment: No point having an index with nothing to point at :) Your indices get dropped with the table.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In Oracle when dropping a table

- all table indexes and domain indexes are dropped
- any triggers defined on the table are dropped
- if table is partitioned, any corresponding local index partitions are dropped
- if the table is a base table for a view or if it is referenced in a stored procedure, function, or package, then these dependent objects are invalidated but not dropped

Answer (score 16):

**In Postgres**

```
DROP TABLE always removes -
1. any indexes
2. rules
3. triggers
4. constraints
that exist for the target table.
```

Comment: Yeeee, rock! Postgres post is the only one with BOLD title

Answer (score 12):

By default, MS Sql Server also drops indexes when a table is dropped.
(Observed in version 13.0.4206.0.)

Answer (score 11):

MySQL also drops table indexes when tables are dropped.

For more info, see [Does dropping a table in MySQL also drop the indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887590/does-dropping-a-table-in-mysql-also-drop-the-indexes)